# How to change color in fade-in and fade-out on div when updating data with sse

Tags: javascript, css, html

When refreshing the data in a div, I have a fade-in fade-out effect whic is working.
But I want to change the colors while I make the fade-in fade-out in order to call attention to the changing value.

The text is changing color, but it always have the last color used. I can't get the desired effect of changing color

how can i do this?

This is the html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="result">Loading data. Please, wait...</div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
                var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");

                source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
                    if (!is_stopped) {
                        $('#result').css('color', 'green');
                        $('#result').fadeOut(1000); 
                        $('#result').css('color', 'red');
                        $('#result').html(event.data + "<br>");
                        $('#result').css('color', 'blue');
                        $('#result').fadeIn(1000);
                    }
                }, false);

                source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
                    // Connection was opened.
                    //alert('Connection opened');
                }, false);

                source.addEventListener('close', function(e) {
                    // Connection was opened.
                    alert('Connection closed');
                }, false);

                source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
                    if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
                    // Connection was closed.
                        alert('Connection closed');
                    }
                }, false);

            } else {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is the php file:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$time = date('r');
echo "retry: 4000\n";
echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
//error_log('XXXX');
flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PeterPam - let's try and break this down to a really specific little piece of the puzzle.

Can you just write out what you're going for?

1. Data fades out
2. new data is inserted to the element
3. color changes / or fades from ______ to _______
4. etc...

That would help. : ) - here's an attempt to simplify to the smallest example.

```
<div id="result">starting thing</div>
<button>do it</button>
```

..

```
function doThings() {
  $('#result')
    .css('color', 'green')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .css('color', 'red')
    .html('other-thing')
    .css('color', 'blue')
    .fadeIn(1000)
  ; // (also) you can 'chain' them like this
}

$('button').on('click', doThings);
```

here's that example: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/8w21gfam/

and here's a possible direction: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/qmhf3vwL/

[`.fadeOut(duration, optionalCallback) {}`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) - check out the details of the function signature. You can use a callback.

help flesh out the animation expectations. : )

Comment: key is callback in fadeOut. Thanks!